# E. Australia Standard Time appears to be one hour early?

Tags: sql-server, timezone

I am trying to learn more about the `sys.time_zone_info` table.  It all seems intuitive except for the E. Australia Standard Time entry found with this query:

```
select current_utc_offset from sys.time_zone_info where  [name] = 'E. Australia Standard Time'
```

I live in the UK and the current UK time is: 22:38.  The current UTC time is: 21:38.  The current time in Sydney, Australia is: 08:38, which is UTC+11.  However, the query above returns this:

```
+10:00
```

and I expect:

```
+11:00
```

I have SQL Server setup as a Docker container. It is SQL Server v18.4.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you want is "AUS Eastern Standard Time". Don't know what the different definitions are but this has DST and more closely resembles the [official names](https://info.australia.gov.au/about-australia/facts-and-figures/time-zones-and-daylight-saving) (if you squint a bit).

Answer (score 1):

OK. I was looking for the difference between those two. however, your question and query result answered my question. Based on your test result. I can see that the 'E. Australia Standard Time' is for the Australian Eastern Standard Time Zone, e.g. Brisbane (Queensland).

The 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' is for the Australian Eastern Standard Time Zone and Australian Eastern Daylight Time Zone, e.g. Sydney (New south wales), Melbourne (Victoria).

- Australian Eastern Daylight Time (AEDT) is in use from the first Sunday in October to the first Sunday in April during Daylight Saving Time (DST). Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST) is used during the remainder of the year.

ref: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aedt

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/196666)